# How to Convert World Coordinates to Camera Image Coordinates?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera, vtk

I'm trying to simulate a Virtual Camera!

I want to compute the projection of a 3D point in a Camera Image Plane.
With reference to [this formula](http://webglfactory.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-convert-world-to-screen.html), I'm converting the 3D World point into 2D Camera Co-Ordinates like this.

```
Point2d World2CameraCoOrdinate(Point3d point3D,const  Affine3d mCameraRT,
                 const Affine3d mCameraIntrinsics,const int width,const int height) 
{
    cout <<"Input World CoOrdinates 3D: " <<point3D<<endl;  

    Affine3d viewProjectionMatrix = mCameraIntrinsics * mCameraRT;

    point3D = viewProjectionMatrix * point3D;

    Point2d ptCamCoOrdinates;

    float winX = (( point3D.x + 1 ) / 2.0) * width ;
    float winY = (( 1 - point3D.y ) / 2.0) * height ;

    ptCamCoOrdinates=Point2d(winX,winY);

    cout <<"Output Camera Co Ordinates 2D: " <<ptCamCoOrdinates<<endl;  

    return ptCamCoOrdinates;
}
```

But I'm not able to compute it correctly &  I'm using OpenCV VTK to verify the results!

VTK Rendered Image Point 2D: 408,150

Estimated Camera Point 2D: 800053, -147570

Here is my complete source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "opengl32.lib" )  
#pragma comment( lib, "glu32.lib" )  

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/plot.hpp>
#include <opencv2/viz.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool bViewFromCamera = false;

void keyboard_callback(const viz::KeyboardEvent &event, void* cookie)
{
  if ( event.action == 0 &&!event.symbol.compare("s") )
    bViewFromCamera = !bViewFromCamera;
}

Point2d World2CameraCoOrdinate(Point3d point3D,const  Affine3d mCameraRT,
                 const Affine3d mCameraIntrinsics,const int width,const int height) 
{
    cout <<"Input World CoOrdinates 3D: " <<point3D<<endl;  

    Affine3d viewProjectionMatrix = mCameraIntrinsics * mCameraRT;

    point3D = viewProjectionMatrix * point3D;

    Point2d ptCamCoOrdinates;

    float winX = (( point3D.x + 1 ) / 2.0) * width ;
    float winY = (( 1 - point3D.y ) / 2.0) * height ;

    ptCamCoOrdinates=Point2d(winX,winY);

    cout <<"Output Camera Co Ordinates 2D: " <<ptCamCoOrdinates<<endl;  

    return ptCamCoOrdinates;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    const int   IMAGE_WIDTH=1176,
                IMAGE_HEIGHT=482;

    const double    fx=1239.911,            
                    fy=1239.911,            
                    cx=519.909,
                    cy=246.656;
    double camMatarray[9] = {fx, 0., cx,
                            0., fy, cy, 
                            0., 0., 1.};
    Matx33d CameraMatrix = Matx33d( fx,  0, cx,
                                     0, fy, cy,
                                     0,  0,  1);


    Point3d pt3dSignPosition_Actual(-1.0,-0.50,5.0),
            Pt3D_Camera;
    Point2d Pt2D_CameraCoOrdinate;

    /// Create 3D windows
    viz::Viz3d Window_3D("World 3D Frame");
    Window_3D.setWindowSize(Size(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT));
    Window_3D.setBackgroundColor(); // black by default
    Window_3D.registerKeyboardCallback(&keyboard_callback);

    Mat RotationVector=Mat::zeros(1,3,CV_64F);
    Mat TranslationVector=Mat::zeros(3,1,CV_64F);

    while(!Window_3D.wasStopped())
    {
        /// Render points as 3D cubes
        Affine3d point_pose(Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F), pt3dSignPosition_Actual);

        viz::WCube cube_widget(Point3f(-0.125,-0.125,0.0), Point3f(0.125,0.125,-0.001), true, viz::Color::blue());
                        cube_widget.setRenderingProperty(viz::LINE_WIDTH, 2.0);
        Window_3D.showWidget("Cube"+string("1"), cube_widget, point_pose);

        // Create a sphere widget
        viz::WSphere sw(Point3d( pt3dSignPosition_Actual), 0.01f);
        // Cast sphere widget to cloud widget
        viz::WCloud cw = sw.cast<viz::WCloud>();
        /// Modify it, and it will be modified in the window.
        cw.setColor(viz::Color::red());

        // Display it in a window
        Window_3D.showWidget("SphereCloudWidget", cw);

        Affine3d cam_pose = (Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F), Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0));

        viz::WCameraPosition cpw(0.125); // Coordinate axes
        viz::WCameraPosition cpw_frustum(CameraMatrix, 0.3,viz::Color::yellow()); // Camera frustum


        if ( bViewFromCamera )
        {
            Window_3D.setViewerPose(cam_pose);

            //For Verifying the Screen Co Ordinates

            Mat mScreenCapture(Size(IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT),CV_8UC3);

            //use fast 4-byte alignment (default anyway) if possible
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, (mScreenCapture.step & 3) ? 1 : 4);

            //set length of one complete row in destination data (doesn't need to equal mScreenCapture.cols)
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, mScreenCapture.step/mScreenCapture.elemSize());

            glReadPixels(0, 0, mScreenCapture.cols, mScreenCapture.rows, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mScreenCapture.data);

            cv::flip(mScreenCapture, mScreenCapture, 0);

            Pt2D_CameraCoOrdinate = World2CameraCoOrdinate(pt3dSignPosition_Actual,cam_pose,CameraMatrix,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT);

            circle(mScreenCapture,Pt2D_CameraCoOrdinate,2,Scalar(0,255,0),2);

            imshow("mScreenCapture",mScreenCapture);
        }
        else
        {
            Window_3D.showWidget("CPW", cpw, cam_pose);
            Window_3D.showWidget("CPW_FRUSTUM", cpw_frustum, cam_pose);
        }

        Window_3D.spinOnce(100, true);
        Window_3D.removeAllWidgets();
    }

    Window_3D.close();
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Figured it out!

1) The VTK Camera Parameters are not Initialised properly.Only Image Size was set properly and all other parameters such as Focal Length, Principal Point are all set to some default values from the input image!

2) The Resultant Camera 2D Image Co-Ordinates were in Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC). i.e Normalised to Depth/Z axis as shown below!

```
Point2d World2CameraCoOrdinate(Point3d point3D,const  Affine3d mCameraRT,
                 const Affine3d mCameraIntrinsics,const int width,const int height) 
{
    Affine3d viewProjectionMatrix = mCameraIntrinsics* mCameraRT;

    point3D = viewProjectionMatrix * point3D;

    point3D.x/=point3D.z;
    point3D.y/=point3D.z;
    point3D.z/=point3D.z;

    Point2d ptCamCoOrdinates(point3D.x,point3D.y);

    return ptCamCoOrdinates;
}
```